# Fetching listgroup from server in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I want to fetch data from server and to show it as list.

server returns json like:

```
{
   "files":["a.txt","b.txt","c.txt"]
}
```

my code looks like:

```
import React ,{ Component }from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

function Watch() {
    const cardContent = {
        display: "flex", 
        flexDirection:"row",
        alignItems: "center" , 
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        cursor:'pointer'
      };

     
      const gridConainer={
        display:'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto'
      };
      getFiles();
      let state;
      function getFiles(){
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/get_videos_list")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
        
      
        state=result;// < --- here I'm taking the array from server
        
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
      }    
  return (
    
  
    <React.Fragment>
    <ul className="list-group">
      {state.files.map(listitem => (
        <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-primary">
          {listitem}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </React.Fragment>

  );
}

export default Watch;
```

But I'm getting error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

When I enter haedcoded like:

```
let state = {
   files: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall"]
};
```

The error is gone and the list created. but the with the hardcoded data and not the data from the server

Comment: Define a local state using useState hook and update using the setState method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `useState` hook.

```
import React ,{ useState } from "react";
//Rest of the imports...

function Watch() {
      const [state, setState] = useState({});
      //Rest of the code...
      //let state; => remove this
      function getFiles(){
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/get_videos_list")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
        setState(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
      }    
//Rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: This is good, however => `useState([])` should have the empty list not the empty object in  as the initial state :)

Comment: I think it needs to be object, because of this line `state.files.map`. Considering this and setting the result fetched directly to the state object. Its good we keep it as an object